# Make background image fit to screen, override bootstrap css padding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i wanna use a background image to fill a block of a homepage.

```
.testTop{
  background: url('/Images/Background/HERO Img.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

so far i can with this css make a image that work good when rescale for every devices. but i can't get it to override the bootstrap css container. so i can't make it fit the whole block width. anyone know how i can override that?

EDIT:

So i think i need to show a sample of what I'm doing.

Html

```
 <html>
    <body>
      <div class="contianer">
        <section class="testTop">
          Fullside background image
        </section>

        <section>
          normal block with text
        </section>
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

So i want the section with the class "testTop" to be a fullsize background image. but i gets the bootstrap container padding. how can i remove this?

thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it only going to be a full sized image background? If so, it doesn't really need to be within the container class?

Comment: it's curse i want it to be place within the section. an the section is within the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want change the style of class `container` permanently, create a new class with `padding-left: 0;` & `padding-right: 0;` and add it beside class `container` like so:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <div class="contianer remove-padding">
        <section class="testTop">
          Fullside background image
        </section>

        <section>
          normal block with text
        </section>
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Then in your css add `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;`

```
.remove-padding {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Or if you want the styles to apply to all the `.container` classes throughout the site just add this:

```
.container {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: but won't this override the container everywhere? i just want to override it on the block(div or section) where i want the image to fill.

Comment: @DaCh so creat a new class and put beside `container` like `<div class="container remove-padding">` with padding left and right 0

Comment: i don't get what you're saying. you think something like this?
<section class="testTop container remove-padding">, curse if i try remove-padding on the div with the container class it will override all the code on the page. i updated my sample to try and show what i got right now.

Comment: @DaCh He means `<div class="contianer remove-padding">`

Comment: Well. it's seems to work. can't really understand why, but it's fixed my problem. Thanks

Comment: @DaCh Because you have two classes as since the second class `remove-padding` is within your own stylesheet it overrides bootstrap styles.

If you inspect the element. You should still see bootstraps `padding` and `margin` just crossed out

Comment: @DaCh i mean you creat whatever name class (in the comment above i call it `remove-padding` - sorry not write it clear in the first place) with attributes `padding-left:0; padding-right:0` and put this class beside class `container` - it will override the attributes of current class `container` in the div you put it, not affect all orther place you put class `container`